# Gerenciando dependências com o Maven em um ambiente offline

Tags: maven

Não sei se o que vou perguntar é simples, ou complexo, mas acontece que comecei a usar o Maven há umas duas semanas na faculdade, em um projeto até um tanto quanto complexo da disciplina de Java EE. Instalei o Maven, tudo certinho no meu notebook e computador pessoal em casa, está tudo ok, mas no meu trabalho a internet é bastante restrita. Após baixar o projeto do GitHub ele não deixa o Maven fazer os downloads da dependência e diz que não foi possível criar a workspace. Existe alguma forma de eu exportar as dependências do notebook e levar para o meu trabalho?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há duas opções principais para trabalhar offline no seu computador usando Maven.

## Baixe tudo antecipadamente

As dependências do Maven ficam na pasta `.m2` dentro do seu diretório de usuário.

Se você sabe que vai trabalhar offline, execute o build [`dependency:go-offline`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) para o maven tentar fazer cache de tudo o que ele precisa para um determinado projeto.

Se for trabalhar em outra máquina, depois de executar o build acima, copie a pasta `.m2` para um pendrive e leve com você. Coloque essa pasta no diretório do usuário do computador de destino e Maven não vai baixar as dependências novamente.

## Ignore o Maven

Também é possível copiar os jars necessários executando o build [`dependency:copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html).

Todos os jars de suas dependências serão copiados para a pasta `target/dependency`. Basta copiá-las para um pendrive e levar com você.

O inconveniente disso é que você terá que desativar o Maven no outro ambiente e adicionar manualmente os jars manualmente, tomando cuidado para não "commitar" por engano as configurações modificadas na sua IDE.

Comment: é isso mesmo! Só uma dúvida, quando eu executo o build dependency:go-offline o maven só tenta fazer o cache ou ele para de baixar? Após salvar a pasta .m2 para por no pendrive, devo ativar de novo? E tenho que usar esse comando na máquina que vou trabalhar offline? Valeu!

Comment: @JoãoNeto Você está confundindo o "modo offline" com o "go-offline". O "go-offline" força o download das dependências. O modo offline impede que o Maven acesse a internet.

Comment: Ahh, agora entendi @utluiz. Muito obrigado, valeu! =DD

Answer (score 0):

Sim, instale o Maven Proxy, configure e execute:

> http://maven-proxy.codehaus.org/

Se você quiser um repositório mais amigável ao usuário, instale o Artifactory:

> http://www.jfrog.com/video/artifactory-1-min-setup/

Comment: Mas por exemplo, se o site do hibernate for bloqueado pelo proxy por exemplo, ele vai baixar do mesmo jeito pelo Maven Proxy?

Comment: São duas coisas diferentes. O Maven Proxy é uma coisa, e o proxy da internet da empresa é outra. [Leia isto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy).

Comment: Eu to ligado, no título coloquei como ambiente offline justamente por isso, por ser o bloqueio da internet da empresa. Então já que a internet não tá disponível preciso de uma solução para passar os arquivos de dependências (já baixados) por um pendrive, algo assim. E toda vez que eu atualiza-se no meu notebook, eu atualizaria no computador sem acesso a internet também. É mais ou menos isso.

Comment: Quando eu atualiza-se no meu notebook atualizaria no computador sem acesso a internet no caso por pendrive novamente.

Comment: Na verdade pelo que eu conheço do Maven Proxy, ele baixa um espelho dos pacotes na sua máquina quando possível. O Artifactory, por sua vez, possui mais opções além da replicação pura e simples.

Comment: No meu caso não é uma opção substituir o Maven pelo Artifactory já que é um projeto acadêmico de uma matéria e têm de ser feito com o maven :( só que eu preciso programa-lo no meu trabalho. Mas ta complicado kkkk.

Comment: Isso não muda nada. O Artifactory é uma implementação de um servidor Maven. Pode usar sim sem problemas.

Comment: Hmmm, entendi, então vou dar uma olhada. Valeu cara.